# How to implement HTML5 Video in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, development, web-part, sharepoint-foundation, video

**Has anyone had any success in building a web-part with HTML5 video and using it in SP 2010?**

***Background:***

Currently I am using JWPlayer by imbedding an HTML page using a content editor web-part.

I did want to use Flowplayer because of the GPL license, but it seems that the CSS breaks sharepoint and I haven't found a work-around.

My current solution won't work for large numbers of users -  I need to create a solution that is plug and play. Stick the web-part on the wiki page, target the source video in a library in the web-part settings, and away you go.

**How would I get started building an HTML5 video solution? Would it be as simple as injecting the HTML using a literal control?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The requirements are of course to update your master page to support HTML 5 (obviously you'll have to use any modern browser to get the benefits of it). The limitations most important are due to the META tag and DOCTYPE (http://klines.org/sharepoint/sharepoint-2010-html5-and-ie9-compatibility-issues/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/>
```

I've succesfully did it after "upgrading" to http://sharepoint2010html5.codeplex.com/ and then using CEWP to embed the VIDEO.

Also very valuable could be http://kyleschaeffer.com/sharepoint/v5-responsive-html5-master-page

Answer (score 2):

I worked on a project embedding JWplayer and Flowplayer into SP2010 and we had some great success with it (it became a product, http://www.ramp.com/solutions/enterprise/, I am not a sales weasal or getting comission ;).

We haven't had anything break SP yet, but I don't know how custom the CSS was for our player. I handled the SP side, and another developer handled the player side and just handed me the code files.

We wanted HTML5 as well, but specifically with SP2010, the browser gets dumbed down to IE8 mode, even if you're running IE10. Most users we were seeing were on IE9, which doesn't support HTML5. We had other components in HTML5, like drag and drop file uploading, but those only worked in Chrome and FireFox.

I would revisit getting FlowPlayer to work, it's doable!

Comment: This is interesting; I simply used the minimalist.css as recommended by the docs: http://flowplayer.org/docs/ and used the CSS Register tag in the master page, and as soon as you do that, you get a "Invalid postback or callback argument. Event validation is enabled [...] " when you try to do anything like upload, etc.

Comment: I would have to now question what CSS we're using, I think we are using a custom one to fit the product. However, simply added a CSS file shouldn't cause postback issues. Try putting the ref to the CSS in a content editor web part for the sake of testing.